# How to use rasterio to store raster data with coordinate system information?

Tags: python, gis, tiff, gdal, rasterio

I use the following code to save the modified raster data. The original data has a complete coordinate system, but the coordinate system information cannot be saved to the new raster data when saving. How should I modify my code

```
for i in range(len(file_names)):
   file_name = file_names[i]
   image = process_tif(file_name)
   with rasterio.open(file_name) as src:
      meta = src.meta.copy()
   with rasterio.open("new_file_name.tif", 'w', **meta) as dst:
      dst.write(image.transpose((2,0,1)))
```

I want the saved raster data to have the same coordinate system information as the original image

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using GDAL instead of rasterio, this is how I project my .tif files. Here we assume a 3 band array, but this supports the 4th if you have RGBA

```
# Open with tif
ds = gdal.Open(tif_file)
# Projecting
arr = np.array(image)
[rows, cols, channels] = arr.shape
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
out_path = 'new_file_name.tif'
outdata = driver.Create(out_path, cols, rows, channels, gdal.GDT_Byte)
outdata.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())
outdata.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())
outdata.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(arr[:,:,0])
outdata.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(arr[:,:,1])
outdata.GetRasterBand(3).WriteArray(arr[:,:,2])
if channels == 4:
    outdata.GetRasterBand(4).WriteArray(arr[:,:,3])
outdata.FlushCache()
outdata = None
ds = None
```